# Установка по USB на Xiaomi

Tags: android

Настраивал отладку по usb на xiaomi(miui 11), включил установку по usb, дело дошло до первого запуска, телефон спросил "позволить ли установку по usb", выбрал "запомнить мой выбор" и, по ошибке, "нет".

Как сбросить настройки отладки по usb? Уже пробовал отключать телефон, вкл/выкл режим разработчика и режим отладки по usb, отзывал разрешения на отладку - всё попусту.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло пересоздание проекта, похоже, запрет действует на конкретную сборку.